# remove baseUrl from Docusaurus site deployed on Github Pages

Tags: github-pages, docusaurus

Hello I have a Docusaurus site in github deployed in Github Pages.

```
"@docusaurus/core": "2.4.1",
"@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs": "^2.4.1",
"@docusaurus/preset-classic": "2.4.1",
"@docusaurus/theme-mermaid": "^2.4.1",
```

Currently the URL for landing page is:

https://catallactic.github.io/catallactic-site/

but I am not able to remove the /catallactic-site/ baseUrl part. The configuration in docusaurus.config.js is:

```
const config = {
  title: 'Catallactic',
  tagline: 'An open source framework and community to build commodity backed crypto currencies',
  favicon: 'img/favicon.ico',

  // Set the production url of your site here
  url: 'https://catallactic.github.io',

  // Set the /<baseUrl>/ pathname under which your site is served
  // For GitHub pages deployment, it is often '/<projectName>/'
  baseUrl: '/catallactic-site/',
  trailingSlash: false,

  // GitHub pages deployment config.
  // If you aren't using GitHub pages, you don't need these.
  organizationName: 'Catallactic', // Usually your GitHub org/user name.
  projectName: 'catallactic-site', // Usually your repo name.

  onBrokenLinks: 'throw',
  onBrokenMarkdownLinks: 'warn',
```

being

```
baseUrl: '/catallactic-site/',
```

If I set

```
baseUrl: '/',
```

I get the following error and the page loses any CSS styles:

```
Your Docusaurus site did not load properly.

A very common reason is a wrong site baseUrl configuration.

Current configured baseUrl = / (default value)

We suggest trying baseUrl = /catallactic-site/
```

which means basically this

[image]

I think this is a quite standard combination. How should be this configured to serve the landing page in the URL: https://catallactic.github.io/ ?

Are we forced to use this baseUrl in Github? Hopefully not.

Answer (score 0):

ok, fixed by adding

1. DNS records in my domain provider

[image]

2. configured a custom domain in Github settings
3. after that, I am able to set baseUrl: '/',

explained here: https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site